# Getting index is outside bounds of the array

Tags: c#, arrays, bounds, out

Could someone explain why do I get this out of bounds?
Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace testing
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            double[] numbers = new double[] { };
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                var input = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                numbers[i] = input;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(numbers);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't set the array size

```
double[] numbers = new double[n]
```

Answer (score 0):

An array is fixed in length upon initialization. Yours has size 0.

```
double[] numbers = new double[] { };  // { } is the same as 'initialize with 0 elements or no content'
```

You need to use a List instead of an Array.

```
List<double> numbers = new List<double>();

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
   var input = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
   numbers.Add(input);
}
```